# Uncaught Error: [$injector:cdep] use ngdialog in factory

Tags: angularjs, http-status-code-401, ng-dialog

I want to use ngdialog to do with the 401 status, but I get the error:Uncaught Error: [$injector:cdep]

```
angular.module('ws.site.master', [
      'ngResource',
      'ngCookies',
      'ngSanitize',
      'ngAnimate',
      'ui.router',
      'ngDialog'
    ]);
```

here I add a factory to do with the 401 status.

```
angular.module('ws.site.master').factory('authHttpResponseInterceptor',['$q','$location','ngDialog',function($q,$location,ngDialog){
  return {
    response: function(response){
      if (response.status === 401) {
        console.log("Response 401");
      }
      return response || $q.when(response);
    },
    responseError: function(rejection) {
      if (rejection.status === 401) {
        console.log("Response Error 401",rejection);
        ngDialog.open({
          template: '/common/templates/at.modal.security.html',
          className: 'ngdialog-theme-default modal-security',
          closeByDocument: false,
          closeByEscape: false,
          trapFocus: false,
          controller: ['$scope', function($scope) {
            $scope.defaultView = defaultView || 'login';
          }]
        });
        $rootScope.isSecurityModal = true;
      }
      return $q.reject(rejection);
    }
  }
}]);
```

here add the authHttpResponseInterceptor to $httpProvider

```
angular.module('ws.site.master').config(['$stateProvider', '$urlRouterProvider', '$locationProvider', '$httpProvider', 'ROUTE',
  function ($stateProvider, $urlRouterProvider, $locationProvider, $httpProvider, ROUTE) {
    $locationProvider.html5Mode(true);
    angular.forEach(ROUTE, function(_route, _name){
      $stateProvider.state(_name, _route);
    });
    $urlRouterProvider.otherwise('/');
    $httpProvider.interceptors.push('authHttpResponseInterceptor');
  }
]);
```

Answer (score 0):

Error: $injector:cdep - Circular Dependency

Please check the angular docs about [this](https://docs.angularjs.org/error/$injector/cdep)

```
angular.module('myApp', [])
.factory('myService', function (myService) {
  // ...
})
.controller('MyCtrl', function ($scope, myService) {
  // ...
});
```

you are injecting 'ngDialog' twice, to you main module and then to factory and all of this is in the same 'ws.site.master'

Comment: I tried to remove the ngdialog in angular.module,but still error. If I remove all the ngdialog, there will be OK. But I need use it:(

Comment: Yeah~ I found the solution~~~~~write a method in rootScope to use the ngdialog, and use it in the authHttpResponseInterceptor~~~~HOHOHO

Answer (score 0):

For dialog window, you have to have bootstrap-tpls included in your html header. And the app should be as follows:

```
angular.module('myModule', [ 'ui.bootstrap']);
```

In controller or factory have:

```
app.controller('myController', function($scope, $modal) {
...
$scope.openPopup = function() {
                    $scope.modalInstance = $modal
                            .open({
                                animation : true,
                                backdrop : 'static',
                                templateUrl : 'yourTemplatePath/template.html',
                                controller : 'yourPopupController'
                            });

                    $scope.modalInstance.result.then(function(returnResult) {
                        $scope.returnResult = returnResult;
                    });
                };
```

Comment: The OP is asking about **ngDialog** / http interceptors binding and not about **ui.bootstrap**'s dialog.